# Replacing the value of a prometheus label as a scalar and not a string?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I know that we can do regex substitution on the value of a Prometheus label. What I want, however, is to do a replacement **treating the value of the label as a scalar**.

Given `metrics{label=value}` (value is actually a number), what I want is a relabeling which gives me `metrics{label=value*1000}`. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Labels are always "string", you can't convert them.

Comment: That is what I suspected. Guess I have no choice but to rewrite the custom library that I cloned.